# Get Image tag from content of post

Tags: posts, loop, attachments

I have create a custom sidebar, and want to show only posts images in that sidebar. I have add a post with some text and choose image from gallery in the content of that post. Now i want to get only image tag from post by loop.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make use of [`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or even [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get the the attached image ID's to the current post

You can then use those ID's to gt the attached image with [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

Here is a basic idea that you can use in a widget or sidebar. (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_status' => null, 
    'post_parent' => get_queried_object_id()
); 

$attachments = get_posts( $args ); 

if ( $attachments ) { 

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { 

        echo '<li>'; 
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); 
        echo  '<p>'; echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title ); 
        echo '</p></li>'; 
    } 
}
```